# How to convert interval to a timestamp in postgresql? and change its default format?

Tags: postgresql, timestamp, converters, intervals

))Hi all,
In postgres I have a table with an Interval datatype coloumn,

Within a thirdapp Im SELECTing one of those Interval rows (via QUERY) cuz I need to compare its value with another "interval" value in this third app.

Well, the case is that this third app, doesn't have an "interval" timetype, so instead Im using a "DateTime" value (equivalent to postgres timestamp).

So in order to compare both (postgres "interval" and thirdapp "Datetime") I need to convert postgres "interval" to "timestamp", to do so Im using this query...

```
SELECT to_timestamp((to_char((SELECT timespan FROM mytable ORDER BY stmtserial DESC LIMIT 1), 'yy-mm-dd HH24:MI:SS.MS')), 'yy-mm-dd HH24:MI:SS.MS')
```

It works, but the result timestamp is shown in this format...

```
MM/DD/YYYY HH12:MI:SS AM
```

starting to count from year 2000, month 1 day 1, so if "interval" = 00:00:00.000 (0 seconds) this will be its "converted to timestamp" result...

```
1/1/2000 12:00:00 AM
```

Is there a way to change this behavior? cuz the thirdapp start to count from...

```
1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM
```

So, there is a gap of 1999 years, Is there a simple way to config or alter this behavior in PostgreSQL so it can start counting from year 0001, or any workaround???

Thanks Advanced.

Comment: Subtract an interval for the difference in epochs.

Comment: How could I do that?? any link, example, pls??